# Parallelization with Gearman

Tags: php, parallel-processing, gearman

I want to parallelize a processing job already handled by Gearman and PHP.
I don't understand the difference between calling `doBackground()` many time  :

```
$gmclient->doBackground("reverse", "Hello!");
$gmclient->doBackground("reverse", "Hello!");
$gmclient->doBackground("reverse", "Hello!");
```

I have enough workers registered, running on their own PID. So the 3 jobs runs in parallel by 3 different workers.

Or using `addTask()`, like said in the docs, explicitly for parallelization.

```
$gmc->addTask("reverse", "Hello World!", null, "1");
$gmc->addTask("reverse", "!dlroW olleH", null, "2");
$gmc->addTask("reverse", "!dlroW olleH", null, "3");

$gmc->runTasks()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `runTasks()` will block until all the tasks added through `addTask()` has completed. Your last example will complete when all the three tasks has completed (add a `sleep()` call to see it in practice), while the first will just kick the tasks over to gearmand and then continue running of the script.

Using `addTask()` to group independent tasks (but related, possibly) makes it easy to do a set of tasks, before doing an operation that assumes that all the previous tasks has been completed. An example could be to resize images in 4 different resolutions, then set the image as active after all four tasks has completed. With `runTasks()` this is easily implemented with four `addTask()` calls, one `runTasks()` and then changing the status of the image, while with doBackground you'll have to poll the state of the tasks you've submitted to gearmand to know when they're finished.

Answer (score 2):

One good point to take here is:

If your Worker is dead or unreachable the doBackground will be WAY better because gearman will receive the workload anyway and than wait UNTIL a Worker exists and do that for you and most of cases ( at least in my experience ) you use gearman to work this way, to send away tasks, workloads and wait they get completed async.

So if your system must be fault tolerant than you probably should use doBackground instead of addTask.... otherwise if you need a STRONG control over y our task THAN addTask will be better.

Hope this can solve for other persons as well...